# Making DLLs available when building Visual Studio project generated with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am converting the build system of a large scale C++ application from SCons to CMake. We depend on more than 20 different software packages that are external to the build tree, these are built by a variety of build systems. I'm now writing Find[package].cmake scripts that exposes these as imported targets to the new CMake build system.

A typical config file can look like this

```
add_library(sqlite SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(sqlite PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION
    "${PACKAGE_ROOT}/sqlite-${sqlite_VERSION}/lib/sqlite.dll"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB
    "${PACKAGE_ROOT}/sqlite-${sqlite_VERSION}/lib/sqlite.lib"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    "${PACKAGE_ROOT}/sqlite-${sqlite_VERSION}/include"
)
```

Whenever I link one of the dlls in my project to the sqlite target, include folders and the necessary link libraries are propagated as appropriate. I can build my project, but it won't run as long as the executable is not aware of the path to sqlite.dll

To solve this, I might want to grab the paths to all IMPORTED_LOCATION files I depend on and append them to the launcher path as described [here](http://cmake.limitpoint.com/setting-the-visual-studio-debugger-path-using-cmake/). The drawback is that I won't be able to run the executable outside of Visual Studio, so someone trying to run python unit tests are going to be disappointed.

Another solution is to pass a list of [package]_DLLs in each package config script, and create a post-build event where DLLs are copied next to the resulting executable. This creates overhead to the build (though probably not prohibitively high). But this pollutes the Find[package] scripts with variables that don't really belong in there.

I'd think that CMake would handle all the IMPORTED_LOCATIONs the executable depends on in a platform agnostic manner, but it seems CMake does nothing to help out in this situation. This puzzles me since I'm sure this must be a problem many developer teams must be facing, and it makes me feel like I've missed something obvious.

UPDATE:
I realize that the standard way is to copy the DLLs to the build folder. The follow-on question is whether there is any standard way for a find_package script to relay information about its run-time dependencies? I've considered to have each package script set two variables e.g. [package]_RUNTIMES_DEBUG and [package]_RUNTIMES_RELEASE and create a target which copies all the files listed in these variables. Further, I need special handling for packages like Qt and Boost where I use the supplied find_package script which don't set any such variable (since, near as I can tell there is no convention for relaying this information)

Comment: You'll have to copy the DLL into a location where the OS can find it.  Also necessary on the user's machine.  Boilerplate is the same directory as your main EXE, the way VS does it when it builds the DLL.  Google "cmake copy dll", top hits are all SO questions.

Comment: I accept that this is the standard way to solve it. But I would like my find_package scripts to pass information about run-time dependencies in a standard way (see edit). Is there any convention for this?